# laravel It is correctly to do like this? Multiple insert to diffrent table from one view form

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna know that it is correctly to something like this. In my database i have table with users and photos. Every one user has exactly one picture. I have
one view with form which is route post to UsersController to store method. 
**UsersController**

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       // some validation

       $user = new Users();
       $user->name = $request->input('name')
       .....
       if($user->save())
       {
         if($request->hasFile('photo'))
         {
              $photo = new Photos();
              ....
              $photo->save();
              return redirect......
         }
       }
    }
```

It is correctly to insert data from one controller to muliple tables. In this example it's only one additional table but every know there may be more of them.

Comment: Use Database transaction for multiple table data entry

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to use the images for other models, it is better to have an image column directly in the users table to avoid the extra work that seems unnecessary to me.

Or if you need to have a different table for images, I suggest you should use Eloquent [`OneToOne` polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations) relationships.

Schema for photos table:

```
photos
    id - integer
    url - string
    photoable_id - integer
    photoable_type - string
```

And in your `Photo` model:

```php
public function photoable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

And in your `User` model:

```php
public function photo()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Photo', 'photoable');
}
```

Now in your controller:

```php
$user = new Users();
$user->name = $request->input('name')
if($user->save())
{
    if($request->hasFile('photo'))
    {
        // Save the file to disk and get it's URL as $photoUrl
        $user->photo()->create([
            'url' => $photoUrl
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now once the photo is saved, you can get the photo for the user using `photo` property on user object, i.e. `$user->photo`. The benefit of this architecture is that you can use the same table to store photos for other models too when needed. You will just need to copy the `photo()` method from `User` model to your other models where you intend to have the photos.

Apart from all this, I see that you have used `Photos` name for the model, but in Laravel, you should always use singular names for models, not the plural ones. So I'd suggest that you should change your model name from `Photos` to `Photo` in order to ensure that you flawlessly use the power of Eloquent without any headache.

Comment: Why OneToOne polymorphic, not just hasOne?

Comment: @simple_code As I explained above, you even don't need a `hasOne()` relationship if you just need to store a photo URL. Use a column directly in the users table. My solution is for advance uses where you would store additional meta data for the object, i.e. for the photo in your case and considering that you would use the `Photo` model for multiple other models.